# Is it possible to listen for em_replacesel message to control in another application in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

This might be a long shot, even not possible.

I was wondering if it is possible to listen for  the `em_replacesel` message to a rich text control in another programs window and then call one of the Win32API's to get the text from the window, or even just get the text that was sent via `em_replacesel`.

Is this possible, and possible in C#?

Answer (score 0):

SetWindowsHookEx will let you inject a DLL into the target process, and hook messages in that process.